# Как лучше сделать добавление пользователя для приложения?

Tags: swift, app

[image]
Стоит задача при нажатии на кнопку "+", добавлять имя пользователя вниз, как лучше сделать?

И дополнительный вопрос, лучше это будет сделать с помощью структуры и массива или coredata и массив? При том что при закрытии приложения надо удалять имена пользователь.

Comment: Ох. При всем уважении, вам сначала надо подтянуть базовые знания в языке. Вообще, решением для данной конкретной задачи будет таблица (причем именно UITableView а не UITableViewController). Но вам сначала надо идти и читать базовые туториалы. CoreData отвечает за сохранение данных в базу, почему вы ее решили противопоставить структуре, я не знаю.

Comment: Спасибо за ответ, понял свои ошибки! ещё на начале своем большого пути, поэтому не претендую на знатока.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Это делается так
Не нужно подключать CoreData, так как хранить данные в базе вам не нужно, а значит мы можем просто записать все в массив
 1. Размещаем на контроллере `tableview`, `textfield`, кнопку добавления
 2. Создаем `cell` в который помещаем имя пользователя и кнопку удалить
 3. Создаем пустой массив
 4. Добавляем `Outlets`
 5. Подключаем `tableview`
 6. Создаем действие на кнопку создать пользователя
 7. Создаем действие на кнопку создать пользователя
 Код `ViewController`

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController, UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource {

var usersArray = [String]()

@IBOutlet weak var tableview: UITableView!
@IBOutlet weak var textfield: UITextField!
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
}
@IBAction func remove_user(_ sender: UIButton) {
    let cell = sender.superview?.superview as! TableViewCell
    let indexPath = tableview.indexPath(for: cell)
    usersArray.remove(at: (indexPath?.row)!)
    tableview.reloadData()
}
@IBAction func add_user(_ sender: UIButton) {
    usersArray.append(self.textfield.text!)
    tableview.reloadData()
}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return usersArray.count
}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "cell", for: indexPath) as! TableViewCell
    cell.username.text = usersArray[indexPath.row]
    return cell
}}
```

Скриншоты
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]